# Relative image paths in html displayed by webkit

Tags: python

I'm using webkit.WebView in Python to display html generated from Markdown. I can display an image from a local file by generating an img tag with an absolute src path, but a realtive path doesn't work. The html with the relative path displays the image OK in Firefox. Is this a known problem with webkit and if so is there a soultion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question .... I realised I was using the WebView's load_string function, rather than writing the html to a file and loading that. This means that there is no html file as a base uri to load the image relative to.

The designers have obviously thought of this and provided a base_uri parameter, which I had just set to "File://". Changing this to a path which makes sense in conjunction with the relative path to the image file fixes the problem.

Hope this will be useful to someone who may have the same problem.